# Widgets not being displayed in FlutterFlow app

Tags: widget, flutterflow

I am working on my first Flutterflow project. (BTW, I am not a developer). It was all going fine but for the past week, I have been facing a strange issue. Some of my pages are unable to display the widgets. There are no errors. I have replaced the widgets, even replaced the pages but the issue is still persistent. There is no error being thrown so I have no idea what is the actual reason. I am attaching the screenshots as well. I would appreciate any help.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cv5DA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGHjb.png)

Comment: Please provide code snippets and tell us what element isn't showing/how you expect it to run specifically.

Comment: It's a no-code platform with no errors, so I am unsure what I should share. If you see the attached images, there is a page named "Create Service" that has an image and multiple text fields. When I run the app, the text fields disappear (as evident from the second screenshot).